# Como saber se uma função em JavaScript é do tipo função assíncrona?

Tags: javascript, funções, tipagem

No código abaixo, podemos usar o [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) para retornar o tipo de determinada variável:

```js
const a = "abc";
const b = true;
const c = () => {};
const d = async () => {};

console.log("typeof a: ", typeof a);
console.log("typeof b: ", typeof b);
console.log("typeof c: ", typeof c);
console.log("typeof d: ", typeof d);
```

No caso das constantes `c` e `d`, o tipo de retorno é o mesmo `"function"`. Acontece que `d` é uma função assíncrona, ou seja, retorna uma `Promise`, o tipo dela ainda é uma função.

Eu gostaria de tratar uma função de *callback* de acordo com o tipo da função (assíncrona ou síncrona):

```
const handler = (error, callback) => {
 // ...
 if (typeof callback ...) { // se for do tipo assíncrona, faz uma coisa
   // ...
 } else { // se não, faz outra
   // ...
 }
}
```

Como eu poderia, **apenas com código e sem auxílio visual de IDEs/Editores**, saber e diferenciar os tipos das constantes `c` e `d`, de uma função síncrona e assíncrona?

Comment: Não seria melhor checar o retorno da função em vez da função em si? `callback() instanteof Promise`

Comment: @Costamilam até poderia, mas minha ideia era executar algum código antes de invocar a função de `callback`. Por isso `callback() instanteof Promise` nao serviria no meu caso.

Comment: Nesse caso, melhor ainda separar em duas funções, como o fs do Node, por exemplo, `readFile` e `readFileSync`

Comment: @Costamilam mas nesse caso, eu não tenho controle de quem for consumir essa função. Se pessoa vai passar uma function async ou nao.

Answer (score 7):

Fora a sugestão da resposta do Woss, você também pode obter por `AsyncFunction.prototype[@@toStringTag]`, se for `async` irá retornar a string `AsyncFunction`, caso não for irá retornar `undefined`

É importante notar funções sem `async` que retornam *Promises* nesse caso irão retornar `undefined` também.

Segue exemplo:

```js
const asyncArrowFunc = async () => {};
const asyncFunc = async function () {};
const syncArrowFunc = () => {};
const promise = () => new Promise((resolve) => resolve());

console.log(asyncArrowFunc, ':', asyncArrowFunc[Symbol.toStringTag]);
console.log(asyncFunc, ':', asyncFunc[Symbol.toStringTag]);
console.log(syncArrowFunc, ':', syncArrowFunc[Symbol.toStringTag]);
console.log(promise, ':', promise[Symbol.toStringTag]);

// Comparando
if (asyncArrowFunc[Symbol.toStringTag] === 'AsyncFunction') {
   console.log("\nÉ async");
} else {
   console.log("\nNão é async");
}
```

### AsyncFunction

O `AsyncFunction` provê os métodos para funções assíncronas, **mas ele não está disponivel no escopo global**, então **inicialmente** não é possível usar algo como:

```js
if (funcao instanceof AsyncFunction)
```

Mas você pode obter o construtor e então usa-lo posteriormente.

Segue exemplo:

```js
var AsyncFunction = (async () => {}).constructor;

var func1 = () => {};
var func2 = async () => {};
var func3 = function () {};
var func4 = async function () {};
var func5 = () => new Promise((resolve) => resolve());

console.log(func1, ':', func1 instanceof AsyncFunction);
console.log(func2, ':', func2 instanceof AsyncFunction);
console.log(func3, ':', func3 instanceof AsyncFunction);
console.log(func4, ':', func4 instanceof AsyncFunction);
console.log(func5, ':', func5 instanceof AsyncFunction);
```

Comment: Percebi o erro, vc copiou a `func4` onde era pra ser a `func5` em `console.log(func5, ':', func4 instanceof AsyncFunction);`

Comment: @CmteCardeal corrigido, foi totalmente falha minha, obrigado!

Answer (score 6):

Pelo que vi, você pode validar isso verificando o nome do construtor do seu objeto através do atributo `objeto.constructor.name`, com ele retornando `AsyncFunction` quando a sua função é assíncrona.

```js
const a = "abc";
const b = true;
const c = () => {};
const d = async () => {};

console.log(a.constructor.name);
console.log(b.constructor.name);
console.log(c.constructor.name);
console.log(d.constructor.name);
```